# How to find the schema-violating keys in a dictionary using jsonschema

Tags: python, jsonschema

I have a dictionary that I am validating against a schema. Is there a way to get the offending key that causes a validation failure?

I have tried the properties of ValidationError given [here](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/).

The message property is nice, but I need the key, and not a string description of the error.

```py
schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
    "price" : {"type" : "number"},
    "name" : {"type" : "string"},
    },
    "additionalProperties": False,
}
try:
    validate(instance={"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 123, "": True}, schema=schema,)
except ValidationError, e:
    print e.message
```

Actual result
Additional properties are not allowed ('' was unexpected)

Expected result(using some other property, hopefully)
''

Comment: You have tried `e.relative_schema_path` and `e.relative_path` as well?

Comment: @SoZettaSho yes, they return the violated schema element deque and an empty deque respectively.

Comment: Unfortunatly with draft-7 and previous, there's no standard output. From draft-8 onwards, there is standard output that will provide you with this infomation. Of course, you'll need to wait for tooling to catch up to draft-8, which isn't even released yet.